# SQL Export to a .csv file using java is breaking on " and ,

Tags: java, sql, export-to-csv

When my exported data is dumped into a .csv file, the following cell is splitting on a comma, such that after the , the text is assigned to a new cell:

misc text "More text" text, more misc text

What are some ways to keep all of the text in one cell?

I've tried putting quotation marks around the comma separated values but the value is still being split.

I can't use external libraries such as Apache or OpenCSV

```
SELECT "('\"'|| value ||'\"') ||','|| ('\"'|| desc ||'\"')" 
FROM table 
WHERE id = "someNumber";
```

The description should remain in one cell but if there is a comma and quotation marks in the string, it will break into a new cell on the comma

Comment: If you have quotes in your data you cant use quotes as column separator, you can use some other value as a column separator, like a bar |, or one you know wont show up in your data.  Either that or find/replace all the quotes in your data before saving to the file.

Comment: I can't understand your SQL statement. What's the meaning of the leading and trailing double quote after the 'SELECT'? What kind of database do you use? With 'value is split' do you mean surely the import in Libre Office or Excel?

Comment: To try and group the value together so when it's opened in excel, the value is not divided "or split" across two cells